# Moving data between sheets based on headers

Tags: vba, excel

Trying to just move data to another worksheet for columns with specified column names

```
Options Explicit
Sub tester()

With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

Dim ar As Variant
Dim i As Integer
Dim j As Long

ar = Array("Header1", "Header2") 'define header names to move

For i = 0 To UBound(ar)
    j = [A1:AW1].Find(ar(i)).Column
    Columns(j).Copy Sheet2.Cells(1, i + 1) 'copy to sheet2 from sheet1
Next I

End With

End Sub
```

But I still keep running into issues and can't debug.

Specifically - I get a compile error that says "invalid outside procedure". When I delete options explicit, I get the runtime error '13' - type mismatch

Comment: "running into issues" isn't very descriptive: usually a more specific outline of the exact problem is more useful.

Comment: @TimWilliams Edited!

Comment: `Option Explicit`  and which line gives the type mismatch?

Comment: Ah, thank you! Fixed Options to option - my mistake. Afterwards, it gives me a variable not defined compile error on the `Columns(j).Copy Sheet2.Cells()` line where Sheet2 is highlighted. That being said, I used Sheet2 for the example, but in my actual case Sheet2 = scratch, so the worksheet name `scratch` is actually what's truly being highlighted.

Comment: Okay, changed the line to `Worksheets("scratch").Cells(1, i+1)` but when debugging, I get the run-time error 91 for a object var / with block variable not set message at the 3rd loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this:

```
Sub tester()

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

        Dim ar As Variant
        Dim i As Long
        Dim j As Long
        Dim f As Range

        ar = Array("Header1", "Header2") 'define header names to move

        For i = 0 To UBound(ar)
            Set f = Nothing '<< added
            Set f = .Range("A1:AW1").Find(arr(i), lookat:=xlwhole)
            If Not f Is Nothing Then
                f.EntireColumn.Copy Sheet2.Cells(1, i + 1) '<< entirecolumn
            End If
        Next i

    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you! When used, I get a "run-time error '1004' - application defined or object defined error"? Additionally, it pulled in all the headers from Sheet1 (with no data) instead of just the 2 headers specified with its' corresponding data

Comment: Seems like it happens on the second run of the for-loop at the last line?

Comment: made a couple of fixes - sorry don't have XL on this PC

Comment: Quick question, if I want to multiply the values being brought in under header1 / header2 by a vlookup formula - can this be done within the for loop or should this be done in a separate sub?

Comment: You should make a separate question for that - you'll need to explain a bit more than would fit into a comment

Comment: Done! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50055747/multiplying-dynamic-range-by-vlookup-value